# Get data of having null values in a specific column & drop other null columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, null

I have a dataframe like this:

```
rawdata = {'col1': [3 ,nan ,4 ,7 ,nan ,5], 
'col2': [10 ,20 ,10 ,30 ,10 ,40], 
'col3': [23 ,34 ,45 ,56 ,34 ,23], 
'col4': [5 ,4 ,nan ,5 ,1 ,nan], 
'col5': [28 ,33 ,33 ,4 ,nan ,44]}
```

What I want is to:

1. Drop all `nan`-including columns except from `col4`
2. Get the data where `col4` is `nan`

Eventually, I need to have below:

```
target = {'col2': [10 ,40],
'col3': [45 ,23], 
'col4': [nan ,nan]}
```

Here is the code:

```
rawdata.drop(["col1", "col5"], axis = 1, inplace= True)
rawdata = rawdata[rawdata.isnull().any(axis=1)][rawdata .columns[rawdata .isnull().any()]]
```

However, this returns me only col4 itself. I need col2 & col3, too.

Comment: Hey, I suggest you to post the code for the dataframe so that we can replicate your dataframe on our side, and help you with your problem. Posting an image of a dataframe is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are okay with just hardcoding the nan-containing columns (as your own example would suggest that you are), this just boils down to `df.drop(['col1', 'col5'], axis=1)[df.col4.isna()]`. With your test data:

```py
In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   3.0    10    23   5.0  28.0
1   NaN    20    34   4.0  33.0
2   4.0    10    45   NaN  33.0
3   7.0    30    56   5.0   4.0
4   NaN    10    34   1.0   NaN
5   5.0    40    23   NaN  44.0

In [14]: df.drop(['col1', 'col5'], axis=1)[df.col4.isna()]
Out[14]:
   col2  col3  col4
2    10    45   NaN
5    40    23   NaN
```

If you would rather not hardcode those columns, a different approach would be

```
In [35]: df.drop(df.columns[df.isna().any()].difference({'col4'}), axis=1)[df.col4.isna()]
Out[35]:
   col2  col3  col4
2    10    45   NaN
5    40    23   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But now, I have another problem. I need to read the column name from a list. Assume there is a list and there is  `'col4'` item there: `mylist = ['col4']`. How am i supposed to do `[df.col4.isna()]` by referring column name to `mylist`.

Comment: @BTurkeli Assuming the column name is the first entry of the list, you could do `df[mylist[0]].isna()`.

Comment: Exactly! This is 'dataframe' spirit which I do not have, yet!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that you have built a dataframe with `df = pd.DataFrame(rawdata)`

I would first build a series containing the columns to keep:

```
keep = df.count() == len(df)
deep['col4'] = True
```

Then what you want is simply:

```
df.loc[df.col4.isna(), keep]
```

which gives as expected:

```
   col2  col3  col4
2    10    45   NaN
5    40    23   NaN
```

If you want a dict, it is just `df.loc[df.col4.isna(), keep].to_dict()`